# Sum of a 4-elem float tuple in OCaml

Tags: tuples, ocaml

I need to write a function that takes a four-element real number tuple as input, and at the output it returns the sum of these numbers.

For example:
  calling: `sum (3., 2., 5., 1) ;;`
  result: `11`.

I know this works:
`(fun (x,y,z,u) -> x+y+z+u) (4,5,6,7);;`
But I want to be able to enter the numbers later.

Edit, my little next question: There are only *fst* and *snd* selectors in OCaml, am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the code you give uses a function expression (also known as a lambda) and doesn't give the function a name.

If you want to call the function later you just need to give it a name. You can use exactly the same expression if you want to:

```
let sum = fun (x, y, z, u) -> x + y + z + u
```

(There is some type disagreement between your description of the problem and this solution.

It's true, there are no pre-defined OCaml functions for retrieving components of tuples with more than 2 elements. You can easily write your own, of course:

```
let fst3 (a, b, c) = a
let snd3 (a, b, c) = b
let thd3 (a, b, c) = c
```

Comment: You can also just bind them where you need it. For example instead of `let t = thd3 x in` you write `let (_, _, t) = x in`. The `_` here means throw that part away.